# Reverting back to Windows XP on laptop - is there a file to update to last set of fixes?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have an older Xerox Documate scanner that will only work with XP. It's barely been used, and I want to set it up on an older laptop. Problem is I upgraded the laptop to Vista. Now, I want to reset it back to it's original state with XP.

I know MS stopped supporting XP, but I was just wondering if there were a file or site that has all the XP service packs and fixes up until they shut it down, so that I can at least put the laptop in the last best state for XP.

Again, I cannot use the Documate with anything other than XP. I will just be using it to scan documents (the thing is fast). I have other CPU's that are more...modern. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revert back to XP, you'll need to re-install XP from a CD - either the OEM version that came with the laptop (e.g. a Dell XP install disc for a Dell laptop) or a retail XP disc. Once installed, Microsoft still will let you download all the last service pack (sp3) and the latest (last) updates. Its a long process, at least 3 hours on an older laptop.

Comment: The media used may include Service Pack 3 and patches... odds are JUST Service Pack 3 and then you'd have to patch.  Make sure once it's updated, you don't connect it to the internet and you keep the firewall enabled as it will be more and more vulnerable to attack since Microsoft is no longer supporting XP.

Comment: Thanks guys, although the Virtualbox idea by @Hannu is tempting, this effectively lets me use an older computer to -slowly- do scanning without interrupting my -gaming- on the other CPU. :)

Answer (score 3):

If your new computer has the RAM and CPU power fit for it - an alternative is to download Virtualbox and install the XP inside it on the new computer. This is how I get my Canon USB scanner going (diff; I run Ubuntu Linux in my computer).

Keep that XP installation OFF the 'net - and you will **not** need any antivirus, firewall or similar; XP is quite nice when kept isolated this way.

Move files via a Virtualbox share, clipboard will copy data between the OS'es if you install the add-on utilties.

Comment: This was tempting, but I want to keep my main CPU free. THanks.